# Qt QObject автоматическая очистка памяти

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

Имеется класс:

```
 #include <QObject>

    class Item : public QObject{
        Q_OBJECT
    private:
        QString m_name;
        uint m_properties;

    public:
        explicit Item (QString _name, uint _properties, QObject *parent = 0);
        ~Item();

        Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
        QString name() const;
        void setName (QString name);

        Q_PROPERTY(uint properties READ properties WRITE setProperties NOTIFY propertiesChanged)
        uint properties() const;
        void setProperties(uint properties);

    signals:
        void nameChanged();
        void propertiesChanged();
    };
```

В другом классе есть метод, допустим он вызывается 10 раз:

```
void Create::addItem()
{
    QList <Item *> dataItem;
    dataItem << new Item ("name1",0) << new Item ("name2",0) <<
                new Item ("name3",0) << new Item ("name4",0) <<
                new Item ("name5",0) << new Item ("name6",0) <<
                new Item ("name7",0) << new Item ("name8",0) <<
                new Item ("name9",1);
    itemModel->addDataItem(dataItem);
}
```

В классе ItemModel есть метод, так же будет вызван 10 раз:

```
void ItemModel::addDataItem(QList<Item *>_data)
{
    dataItemList.append(_data);
}
```

В классе ItemModel переменная dataItemList объявлена как

```
QList<QList<Item *>> dataItemList;
```

В ней должно хранится 10 листов в кажлм из 10 по 9 объектов класса Item.

Так вот, в какой-то момент времени у объектов класса Item вызывается деструктор, и уже dataItemList указывает на освобождённую память. Как обойти данную проблему, чтобы Qt не удалял данные объекты, а удалил их я когда мне это будет нужно?

Огромное спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: `new Item ("name1",0)` вообще, вы не передаете родителя, деструкторы не должны вызываться никогда

Comment: Как то все сложно-сложно написано, но думаю, что QSharedPtr поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Очень плохой дизайн. Правильно:

```
void Create::addItem()
{
    QList <Item> dataItem;
    dataItem << Item ("name1",0) << Item ("name2",0) <<
                Item ("name3",0) << Item ("name4",0) <<
                Item ("name5",0) << Item ("name6",0) <<
                Item ("name7",0) << Item ("name8",0) <<
                Item ("name9",1);
    itemModel->addDataItem(dataItem);
}

...

void ItemModel::addDataItem(QList<Item >_data)
{
    dataItemList.append(_data);
}

... 

QList<QList<Item>> dataItemList;
```

Возможно компилятор попросит вас сделать конструктор копирования. 
Что то типа

```
explicit Item ( const Item &item);
```

в *class Item*. Но это будет легче чем бороться с текущими глюками и потом утечками памяти.
Избегайте *new* как можете. Это очень коварная штука!